# How to access gmail attachment from my application?

Tags: android, email-attachments

I have seen some questions related this question, but i am not getting about getContentResolver().query(); method ;  How it is related to gmail?,How to get file from gmail to my application without download the file

Comment: Simple answer You can't.

Comment: why ?,   for example if you take contacts backup and restore,in this they store that contacts file into gmail ,and when ever we want we can restore without download the file.

Comment: `they store that contacts file into gmail` ? What do you mean exactly? Does it have to do anyting with sending/receiving emails?

Comment: Means if i will take Backup from my phone then it send one file like "vcard.vcf" to my mail,then after that we can use that file,             SO my question is "how to directly restore that file(through mail)" to my application without downloading the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible directly

we have to use external api like gmail api in java and integrate that gmail api to our android application

here is the link for gmail api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/